# Como pegar inputs com jquery e ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

estou com a seguinte duvida tenho uma aplicação web que quero ao fazer login na pagina inicial "index.html" pegar o 'nome' e 'email' e colocar com jquery em uma outra pagina 'paginaprincipal.html' .

exemplo:
index.html

```
   <form name="form-login" id="MyForm">
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" required>
        <input id="senha" type="password" name="senha" required>

        <button type="submit" id="btnLogin">Acessar</button>
   </form>
```

paginaprincipal.html

```
<div id="pega">
      Nome: <p id="nome"></p>
      Email: <p id="nome"></p>
</div>
```

observação: antes da pagina principal ainda tenho mais duas paginas anteriores

---

Exemplo:
tenho uma index com login que esta funcionando com ajax e php:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

uma pagina entre a index e principal

e por fim tenho minha pagina principal onde quero reculperar os dados la do login da index.html
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Um jeito de fazer isso seria armazenar os valores em cookie, dá uma olhada nessa resposta aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599367/6101515

Comment: so não estou entendendo como ficaria meu php verifica_login.php e esse calback msg == ok... success: function(msg){ if(msg=='ok'){ $("#retorno_log").html(msg); else{ window.location.href='home_page.php'; } } } poderia ser mais claro pois ainda sou iniciante em programação web

Comment: o arquivo `verifica_login` que sugeri, faria o select no banco de dados para ver se o usuário digitou as informações corretamente, vou atualizar minha resposta pra te ajudar.

Comment: certo no aguardo amigo

Comment: atualizei mas apareceu em outra resposta, não entendi. Enfim, vi que o JuniorNunes deu uma resposta exatamente sobre o que você perguntou. Se eu fosse guardar informações em outra página, guardaria usando sessão do php. Ainda precisa?

Comment: Alan, por favor não use a área de resposta para postar complementos ou novas dúvidas. Use esta área aqui de comentários, ou edite sua pergunta (exceto se já tiverem respondido e a edição for invalidar as respostas existentes).

Comment: Ok é minha primeira pergunta no forum rsrs

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como pegar dados de um form de outra pagina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236625/como-pegar-dados-de-um-form-de-outra-pagina). Por mais que esta seja mais antiga, a nova está melhor formatada.