# Como pegar dados de um form de outra pagina

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Olá pessoal estou com a seguinte duvida tenho uma aplicação web que quero ao fazer login na pagina inicial "index.html" pegar o 'nome' e 'email' e colocar com jquery em uma outra pagina com php, ajax e jquery 'paginaprincipal.html' .

exemplo: index.html

```
<form name="form-login" id="MyForm">
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" required>
        <input id="senha" type="password" name="senha" required>

        <button type="submit" id="btnLogin">Acessar</button>
   </form>
```

paginaprincipal.html

```
<div id="pega">
      Nome: <p id="nome"></p>
      Email: <p id="nome"></p>
</div>
```

observação: antes da pagina principal ainda tenho mais duas paginas anteriores

Exemplo:
tenho uma index com login que esta funcionando com ajax e php: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

uma pagina entre a index e principal

e por fim tenho minha paginaprincipal.html onde quero reculperar os dados la do login da index.html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

espero ter sido claro agradeço quem poder ajudar...

meu codigo php de login:

```
<?php

require './connection.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario_app WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha');
$stm->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->bindParam(':senha', $_POST['senha'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();

if ($linha = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Bem vindo {$linha['nome']}";
} else {
    echo 'Erro ao efetuar login!';
}
```

meu js de login:

```
    $('#btnLogin').click(function () {

    var url = "http://localhost:/projeto/login.php";

    $.post(url, $('#MyForm :input').serializeArray(), function (data) {
        navigator.notification.alert(data, null, "MSG", "OK");
            alert(data);
            window.location.href = 'pagina_principal.html';
        });
    });


$('#MyForm').submit(function () {//PARA PAGINA NÃO CARREGAR NOVAMENTE
    return false;
});
```

meu ajax para pegar os dados:

```
    var reculpera = $("#MyForm").serialize();//form login #MyForm
$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:/projeto/login.php",
    data: reculpera

}).done(function (data) {
    localStorage.setItem('nome', data.nome);
    $("#pegaemail").text(localStorage.nome);
//    alert(data.nome);

}).fail(function () {
    alert("erro");
});
```

resultado do meu ajax para jogar nessa linha

```
$("#pegaemail").text(localStorage.nome);
```

resultado #pegaemail está dando a mensagem de 'undefined' erro no ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que enviar os dados pro servidor, e depois mandar esses dados de volta com sua página principal. Pra fazer isso, não é possível usando html puro, você deve usar php ou alguma outra linguagem no servidor pra poder processar essas informações.

Comment: pesquisando sobre descobri isso quero pegar com php e depois com ajax e jquery retornar os valores pra pagina principal, teria como exemplificar?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar um `BackEnd` para isso. Vou dar um exemplo para ficar mais claro.

`EXEMPLO1` - `PHP`

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="URL.PHP">
   <input type="text" name="email">
   <input type="password" name="senha">
</form>

<?php
   session_start();
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $senha = $_POST['senha'];

   $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = ? AND senha = ?");
   $sql->execute(array($email, $senha));

   $ln = $sql->fetchObject();

   $_SESSION['nome'] = $ln->nome;
 ?>
```

Ja na pagina inicial seria so assim...

`<h1><?= $_SESSION['nome']; ?></h1>`

Porem é importante que você estude para entender. Você pode procurar sobre `PHP + PDO.`

Segue alguns links que podem te ajudar.

1. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php)
2. [MYSQL](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php)
3. [LOGIN COM PHP E PDO](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criando-um-sistema-de-login-com-php-e-mysql)

Eu aconselho da uma estudada a mais na linguagem, te ajudara bastante.

ATUALIZAÇÃO:

```
<?php

require './connection.php';
$retorno = array();

$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario_app WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha');
$stm->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->bindParam(':senha', $_POST['senha'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();

if ($linha = $stm->fetchObject()) {
    $retorno['erro'] = false;
    $retorno['nome'] = $linha->nome;
} else {
    $retorno['erro'] = true;
}


$('#btnLogin').click(function () {
    var url = "http://localhost:/projeto/login.php";
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url,
       data: $('#MyForm').serialize(),
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){
           var mensagem = data.erro ? 'NAO LOGADO' : 'LOGADO'

           if(data.erro){
               navigator.notification.alert(mensagem, null, "MSG", "OK");

           }else{
               navigator.notification.alert(mensagem, null, "MSG", "OK");
               localStorage.setItem('nome', data.nome)
           }

       }
    })
});

$('#MyForm').submit(function () {//PARA PAGINA NÃO CARREGAR NOVAMENTE
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Vou mudar o front-end pro usuário fazer o login ja dentro da tela principal dai fica mais facil pegar esses dados. abraço

Comment: @Alan Abraços, qualquer duvida que tiver, pode comentar la nas aulas tambem.